# Is it possible to edit an IntellijIDEA project remotely via a web browser?

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-access

I am looking for something similar to RStudio-server ([r-studio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/download/)), but for programming in Java/Scala.
RStudio-server accessed via web is the same as the desktop version.

May be there are other equivalent solutions, given that my problem is scarce local resources to run my programs, but plenty of resources in a remote computer.

The more seamless, the better.
It would be also good if I could just run my program remotely seamlessly (outputing like if it was local and inside the IDE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not seamless, but I just managed to solve the problem using the right workflow:

In the ***local*** machine:

1. **edit** files in IDEA
2. [optional] **set** the output path, if any, to your favorite *file hosting service* (*dropbox* in my case)
3. **commit** with your favorite VCS (*bzr* in my case, it can need a push to the remote machine)

In the ***remote*** machine:

1. **update** with your favorite VCS
2. **compile and run** with your favorite build tool (*sbt* in my case):

   ```
   sbt 'run-main experiments.AtomicBombMain'
   ```

[optional] In the ***local*** machine again:

1. [optional] **get** the generated files at the output path at the shared folder of your favorite *file hosting service*

Link with more details about the entire process since instalation until compiling:
[sbt-intellij-idea-scala-debian-wheezy-how-to](http://neglectorientedprogramming.tumblr.com/post/68855288107/sbt-intellij-idea-scala-debian-wheezy-how-to-best)

Answer (score 0):

I recently starting using [Chromoting](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) to remote into a different machine that has IntelliJ.  It's convenient in that it's built into chrome and I can pretty much do this anywhere because everyone has Chrome these days.  It's a very good remoting tool but it still is remoting, it has its delays and minor problems (some keyboard shortcuts don't get sent through and those options haven't been added yet).

Just an idea for something to try.